# Import 1st Sheet From Folder Except One Named File Import 2nd Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to import the first sheet of all files in a folder that I select and rename to their original file name except for one. If the file Forecast Report exists in the files, I want to copy the second sheet.

I have tried a code that imports all sheets from all files but this is excessive because I then must go in and delete many extra sheets. The code I have below works great for importing my files. I am looking for a way to add to this "if Forecast Report exists, copy the 2nd sheet."

```
Sub My Data()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim s As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Title = "Select all reports:"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All Excel Files", "*.xl*"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        Workbooks.Open.SelectedItems (i)

            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)

            With ActiveWorkbook
                s = .Name
                .Sheets(1).Copy     After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = Split(s, ".")(0)
                .Close 0
            End With
        Next


    End If
End With


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IF` statement to test if `ActiveWorkbook.name` is "Forecast Report.xlsx" (change the extension as needed). If found copy `.Sheets(2)`, etc. If not found then copy `.Sheets(1)`

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    s = .Name

    If s = "Forecast Report.xlsx" Then
        .Sheets(2).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = Split(s, ".")(0)

    Else
        .Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = Split(s, ".")(0)

    End If

End With
```